# Is this the fastest way of testing the primality of a number

Tags: c++, primes

```
bool is_prime(int num)
{
    if(num < 2)
        return false;

    int sq = std::sqrt(num);

    for(int i = 3; i <= sq; ++i, ++i)
        if(num % i == 0)
             return false;

    return true;
}
```

We only need to check upto square root.
Proof -> https://scienceparv.blogspot.com/2021/07/mathematics-if-one-divisor-of-dividend.html

Comment: Trying to make sense of the timeline here, looks like this specific question would be better off abandoned (& eventually cleaned-up); it's on hold for broken code but has answers that would be invalidated if the OP is edited to fix it now - simplest would be to make a new post, this time putting up code that is review-ready and working as intended (incorrectness in unexpected edge cases might still get pointed out by reviewers, but the idea is that your code works as intended to begin with), that way it's easier to avoid editing questions after they receive answers. Cheers!

Comment: Already closed as "not suitable for site", reopened by adding a paren to fix the typo.  But, previous identical edit was reverted as "don't edit the code after posting".  Regardless of this typo, this is a question not a code review.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, the indentation is weird following the first `return false;`, as well as some incorrect parentheses, which leads to the code being impossible to compile.

You need to include `<cmath>` in order to have access to the `std::sqrt` function.

<del>You don't need two `++i`s in your `for` loop.</del>

You can group together the case that the number is even (and not a 2) at the end.

Altogether, I came up with this example:

```cpp
#include<cmath>
bool is_prime(int num)
{
    if(num <= 1)
        return false;
    if(num == 2)
        return true;
    int sq = std::sqrt(num);

    for(int i = 3; i <= sq; i += 2)
        if(num % i == 0)
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

And to answer your question, this is not the fastest way. You might want to do some research on [fast deterministic primality tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Fast_deterministic_tests).

Comment: @parv I can't comment on the original post (low reputation) but the error messages can be found here: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/BLayh3x0) (the file was named test.cpp)

Comment: If you see a comment indicating the question is off-topic or it might be better not to answer.

Comment: Welcome to code review, you made some good observations.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Just to make sure, in the future, should I not improve dysfunctional code like this on Code Review?

Comment: If it won't obviously compile, ignore it or put it in a comment. Be wary of questions that have a negative score. If you see a comment like Zeta's or mine don't answer. Other than that feel free to help improve code.

Comment: @EricChen it's a matter of scoping and single responsibility: each site on the network has a well-defined scope & purpose; questions involving coding issues and broken code should be asked as a "minimal reproducible example"; users that want to help others fix their code go to Stack Overflow. CR wants to see the real, working, review-ready code (would you submit a pull request with it?), see [A Guide to CR for SO users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777/23788) for all the details. Welcome aboard!

Comment: Including `<cmath>` gives you access to the **`std::sqrt()`** function, so one should qualify it correctly (or include `<math.h>` instead, but I don't recommend that).

Comment: BTW, the two `++i` is because OP tested `num%2==0` already, and so only needs to check odd numbers in the for loop.

Comment: You misspelt `std::sqrt`.  And `is_prime(-1)` remains as broken as the original...

Answer (score 4):

### Fix your indentation.

Your indentation is messed up.

---

This is silly:

```
++i, ++i
```

Make it readable:

```
i += 2
```

---

You jump by two (as you know all even numbers, except 2, are not prime). But you can improve that by jumping by 2 or 4. This is because we know that all multiples of 2 and 3 are not prime and every third 2 lines up with every second 3 but this makes a pattern so you can jump by 2 then 4 then 2 then 4 etc.

```
 bool isPrime(int val)
 {
     if (val == 2 || val == 3) {
         return true;
     }
     if (val < 2 || val % 2 == 0 || val % 3 == 0) {
         return false;
     }

     int sq   = sqrt(val);
     int step = 4;
     for(int i = 5; i <= sq; i += step)
     {
         if (num % i == 0) {
              return false;
         }
         step = 6 - step;
     }
     return true;
 }
```

---

This is fine for small numbers. But once you start looking at large primes you need to use the "Sieve of Eratosthenes".

Basically you don't need to try every number you just need to try all the primes below your number. So keep track of all the numbers you have thrown away (because they are multiples of a lower prime) and check those against your numbers.

Comment: Have you missed division by 7?

Comment: @bipll: No. Its subtle. `step = 4` outside the loop. The first iteration of the loop sets `step = 6 - step;` which makes `step = 2`. Now the increment operation kicks in. `i += step` => `i = i + step` => `i = 5 + 2`. So the second iteration is `i = 7`.

Comment: @MartinYork oh, sorry, I've missed it.

Comment: @Martin York ++i, ++i is faster than i += 2 because in the latter adder circuit is used.

Comment: @parv You don't program in assembler, nor use a dumb compiler, but a modern optimizing compiler. Such convolutions thus just impact readability, nothing else.

Comment: @parv. If the compiler you are using does not optimize to the same instructions (I suppose you could have an old compiler). Then sure, use your technique. **BUT** you should add some detailed comments about why in the code is written like that with lots of details. Otherwise a maintainer is going to come along and look at that and have the same reaction as me and remove it.

Comment: @parv Did you not look at this after posting if for 17 months?

Comment: @Martin York oh!!